# What is the easiest way to front my grails application with LightHTTPD during development?

Tags: grails, lighttpd

I'm not familiar with LightHTTPD and haven't been able to find any guides on how to configure this.  I attempted reading the docs and configuring it a while back but failed....

What is the easiest way to front my grails application in development with LightHTTPD"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably look at starting and stopping it using the events hooks available via _Events.groovy.

Are you just going to use it to serve static content or to proxy all requests to Grails?

Comment: Looking to just proxy all requests to grails for development. (Reason being for developing some functionality against OAuth)

Comment: In that case, use one of the event hooks to configure and start it programatically (does it have a Java API?) before your application starts.